# Rspec and testing xml response

Tags: ruby, xml, rspec

Using rspec in ruby, How would I test a parsing method I have that parses xml. Would I create an xml fixture and run it through my method?

Comment: Basically yes. You should test the specific behaviour of your method though, so it may be worth posting more details of what it does. Does it really parse XML itself, or is it relying on an already-tested library (e.g. Nokogiri), and extracting specific data? There's no need to re-test all of Nokogiri's behaviour. That might mean you can use short xml strings in your test, if your method  takes them as input (or if it takes `Nokogiri::XML::Document` objects), and XML suitable for testing is simple enough. If it takes a file path though, you'll want file-based fixtures

Comment: Thanks Neil, my method actually takes a Savon response object, I am using Savon to interface with a SOAP API. Should I attempt to create a fixture of the Savon response object and pass that through my methods?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Savon, but essentially yes this makes sense for a unit test of the method, especially if it is part of the public interface to your module or class. You could probably write a helper method that generated a Savon response object from a file fixture, and use that to provide inputs for your test.